# Mitigating TCP slow start in web applications

Tags: web-applications, tcp, tcp-slow-start

What steps can developers take at the application level to mitigate the effects of TCP slow start on high-bandwidth, high-latency networks such as LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most simple answers is to check that HTTP/1.1 keep alive is enabled, I guess. Server shouldn't send `Connection: close` header. This will allow browser to use limited number of TCP connections to request resources. Those connections TCP congestion window will grow allowing further requests to use LTE bandwidth more effectively.

More advanced solutions would be to use HTTP/2 which doesn't have such violent limitations on request pipelining. A lot of data could be easily pipelined in one connection.